# tvOS: YouTube Player with subtitles

Tags: swift, youtube-api, tvos

I implemented a tvOS App that allows to browse YouTube playlists and play their videos. On web I simply can enable subtitles. But via the api this doesn’t seem to be supported. Is the no flag on YouTube to render subtitles in the stream?
How do I achieve this?

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Code does not help as the currently used library doesn’t support subtitles.

Comment: Subtitles are a separate file format. The answer will depend on what video format, and player you're using. Could you also provide the JSON response for an example YT video in your question.